# callback function access to closure variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures, promise

The following piece of code has a bug but it opened an interesting question. Its using an angular's $http service which returns a promise. Once resolved, the callback function does not have access to the s1 variable.

```
    var ids = [];
    ids = ['81074'];

    // show what's in
    for (var s=0;s<ids.length;s++) {
        var s1 = s;
        $http.get('http://mydomain.com/api/catalog/product/' + ids[s]).
                 success(function(data) {
        // console.log(s1); <--- reference error
            $scope.products[s].setProductData(data);

        }).error(function(err){
                console.log('--------- error',err);
            });
    };
```

s1 gives ReferenceError: s1 is not defined in the debugger

And interestingly, it does have access to the for loop variable s, which is always 1 - as expected, since the promise got resolved after its incremented (hence the bug BTW)

Can someone explains why?

thanks

Lior

Comment: I don't see any use of `s1`, where is the error happening?

Comment: Your code doesn't reference s1 anywhere after it is defined. How can you be getting a reference error?

Comment: i checked s1 in the debugger, while inside the callback. code edited. thanks for the remarks

Comment: my mistake - when added properly with console.log it works. thanks! The lesson is, debugger cannot see closure variable unless they are explicit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a classic issue with asynchronous callbacks in a `for` loop. Both `s` and `s1` are only declared once. Even though you declare `var s1;` within the loop, JavaScript has no block scope, so it's irrelevant.

This means all iterations share the same variables `s` and `s1`, so when the callback completes, `$scope.products[s]` is looking up the `ids.length + 1` product.

Instead, do:

```
var ids = [];
ids = ['81074'];

function launchRequest(s) {
    $http.get('http://example.com/api/catalog/product/' + ids[s]).success(function (data) {
        $scope.products[s].setProductData(data);
    }).error(function (err) {
        console.log('--------- error', err);
    });
}

// show what's in
for (var s = 0; s < ids.length; s++) {
    launchRequest(s);
}
```

... which introduces a new function level scope inside `launchRequest`, which means `s` is still `s` inside the function when the callback resolves.

Comment: thanks @Matt, i understand about s, and thanks for your suggestion! (taken). Still, in the original code, why is s1 not visible inside the callback? what should I do to get s1 to be visible there?

Comment: ok - figured it out. sorry - my bug. s1 is visible, as long as you explicitly write it.